Why can't we make liquid crystal displays out of soap?
Liquid Crystal Displays (LCDs) are widely used everywhere, especially in the screens of computer monitors, TVs, and small devices like thermostats. As its name suggests, LCDs use substances with liquid crystal properties.
Soap is one of these substances. It's also pretty inexpensive, so why aren't we using soap for the liquid crystal layer of the LCDs?

Soap is too ambiguous term.

Making effective liquid crystals that work in displays is much harder than you think
Effective liquid crystal displays require a number of specific properties of the liquid crystal substance to be just right at the temperatures a display normally has to operate at. Many substances can only form liquid crystal phase at ridiculous temperatures, so they are ruled out. The very first liquid crystals, discovered in the early 1960s, with some of the right properties (based on para-azoxyanisole compounds) only worked above 116°C, which isn't very practical for a display.
Another property that matters in effective displays is that the liquid crystal state can rotate polarised light and the state can be controlled by an electric field. Rotating polarised light is the key feature needed for liquid crystal displays. But not all liquid crystals do this well or do this quickly enough to be useful in displays.
So a lot of fine tuning of the detailed properties was required before the substances could be used commercially. New types of compound and mixtures of compound with increasingly better properties had to be developed before any products were practically useful. Research is still continuing to improve the properties of displays.
So you can't just take a cheap compound like sodium stearate (which is basically what common soap is) and make a display with it.
